# Is there an analogue of DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthDayPattern Property in Java?

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I am looking for something similar to [MonthDayPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthdaypattern%28v=vs.90%29) in Java.

I have tried DateFormatSimbols, SimpleDateFormat, DateFormat etc.

.Net returns a particular MonthDayPattern for each locale.

If I am right .Net returns "dd MMMM" for the culture "en-NZ" and "MMMM dd" for the "en-US"
I don't understand the rules which the pattern built with.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The patten has no good rule, this is differently depending on national and local traditions. And this case is more complex for full date format as 12/08/01 that can read as 2012-08-01 or 2001-08-12 or 2012-01-01.

Comment: ok, but .Net got it from somewhere, right? maybe there is some ISOblablabla standard or smth like this.

Comment: Is this page to help for you: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatTimeDef.html

Comment: ok thanks I have seen this. In .Net they have MonthDayPattern and YearMonthPattern to parse ambiguous strings like "September 06". It seems Java didn't bother

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is of any use, but you may find Joda Time useful in and of itself, and the following method may help you out:

[Joda Time's "Pattern for Style" method](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#patternForStyle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29)

Joda Time is worlds better than the default Java date and time libraries.  Calendar and Date in particular are nasty, DateTime and its like in JodaTime are much simpler to use.